# java command fails in node js child process exec but succeeds on command line

Tags: java, node.js, runtime-error, openxml, child-process

I am trying to run the following command using the node JS child process exec package:

```
java -Duser.dir=/app/system/controllers/ -jar -Xmx2048m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit "/app/system/controllers/validation/dist/Validation.jar" "load" "ATC" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile1.xlsx" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile2.xlsx"
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execSync;

var child = exec('java -Duser.dir=/app/system/controllers/ -jar -Xmx2048m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit "/app/system/controllers/validation/dist/Validation.jar" "load" "ATC" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile1.xlsx" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile2.xlsx"', function (error, stdout, stderr){
                if(error){
                    console.log("The error is: ",error);
                }
            });
```

For some reason, when I call it like that, it gives the following error:

```
Error: Command failed: java -Duser.dir=/app/system/controllers/ -jar -Xmx2048m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit "/app/system/controllers/validation/dist/Validation.jar" "load" "ATC" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile1.xlsx" "/app/system/controllers/validation/test files/uploadedfile2.xlsx"
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:290)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:774)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:344)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
```

But, when I run it via the command line by literally just copying and pasting it, it works completely fine.  Would there be a simple explanation for why this is happening? Am I calling something wrong in the child process call?

Comment: But then why will it work on the command line with no errors? I copy and paste the command given in the error message and run it

Comment: In my test, in similar code occurred error caused by ```-Duser.dir=/app/system/controllers/```. Check you!!

Answer (score 0):

I know it’s been two years since this question has been asked. However, I recently had the same issue and found that if you create a shell file in the projects main directory, you can call it with a spawn function. You just have to provide at least one argument for it to work.

This is even if the shell script is not set up to handle the argument. Otherwise, it will put ENOENT at the end of the command for some reason. I am on mobile at the moment, but will be editing this later to provide a code sample.